# How do I resolve "failed to find style 'bottomnavigationstyle'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've been trying to add `BottomNavigationView` to my Activity but I've got a rendering problem which says :

```
"failed to find style 'bottomnavigationstyle' in current theme".
```

I've added this dependency (didn't throw any error, so I'm assuming it exists)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Can you show your `BottomNavigation` xml code

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_options"
        /> @UmangBurman

Comment: Can you edit in the question the `BottomNavigationView` and the theme styles.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try after updating your android studio and supported libraries.
My gradle:app config are:-

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Comment: there is no error in the your xml code i tried on my android studio

Comment: But I'm using API 28

Answer (score 1):

I had to upgrade my gradle. It works now!